# How do I get the last record in a groupby() in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` which has a number of records for each student.  Frequently I want to get the one with the last timestamp.

What is the best way to do this?  Previously I had been using `last()` but this gives the last *non null* value when really I just want the last value, null or otherwise.

Using `apply(lambda r: r.iloc[-1])` works, but the code feels ugly (I hate using an `apply` and anecdotally it feels slow and inefficient, likely because of the apply).

What is the right way to do this?

```
(Pdb) df = pd.DataFrame([["A",2,3],["B",5,6],["A",np.NaN,4]], columns=["student", "value_a", "timestamp"]).sort_values("timestamp")
(Pdb) df
  student  value_a  timestamp
0       A      2.0          3
2       A      NaN          4
1       B      5.0          6

(Pdb) df.groupby("student").last()
# This gives the wrong answer
         value_a  timestamp
student                    
A            2.0          4
B            5.0          6

(Pdb) df.groupby("student").apply(lambda r: r.iloc[-1])
# This gives the right answer but feels inefficient
        student  value_a  timestamp
student                            
A             A      NaN          4
B             B      5.0          6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to sort your dataframe first if you choose to use `nth` or `tail`. After that you can drop the dupes:

```
>>> df.sort_values('timestamp').drop_duplicates('student', keep='last')
  student  value_a  timestamp
2       A      NaN          4
1       B      5.0          6
```

Comment: No groupby needed.  :) +1

Comment: I like! But a but verbose.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use [`groupby.tail`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.tail.html):

```
df.groupby('student').tail(1)
```

Output:

```
  student  value_a  timestamp
2       A      NaN          4
1       B      5.0          6
```

Note that if you want the last timestamp, another option is to index with [`groupby.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html):

```
df.loc[df.groupby('student')['timestamp'].idxmax()]
```

Comment: Note: this is almost exactly what I wanted except that it will result in output that is not indexed by the groupby column.  Which is sometimes why you need!

Answer (score 4):

You can try `.nth`:

```py
out = df.groupby('student').nth(-1)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
         value_a  timestamp
student                    
A            NaN          4
B            5.0          6
```

Comment: This is the one that worked for me - same output structure/format as last() except without overwriting null values.